# Add a more easy way to filter by tags on Android

Tags: feature-request, android-app

In the android app there is no easy way to filter questions by tag like on the web app. On the web app I can see favorite tags on the right and click on one of them directly to filter questions to area of my interest. But in the android app, **I need to find a question of that category, open it and then click on the tag to filter.**

Also, on the web app the tags below each question (on home page) is clickable and can be used to filter questions containing that tag. In the android app, the tags are displayed (on home page) but aren't clickable (like inside the question). Can they be made clickable and enable filtering using those so that it is easier to reach the intended list if questions?

Comment: *"I need to find a question of that category, open it and then click on the tag to filter."* Huh? Just go to the main site (where you see the unfiltered questions), click on "Stack Overflow" in the top blue bar, select "tags" and then select your desired tag.

Comment: yup just checked that. almost same number of steps as in going to question and clicking tag. Why cant we make the tags below questions clickable? Just wondering.

Comment: You mean the small gray tags under the question on the main site? This would cause too many misclicks between "want to open the question" <-> "want to select the tag", since it's too small. Or you're on a tablet.

Comment: hmmm... possible.

Comment: But it is quite strange that you can't define your favorite tags to always filter for them. At least I haven't found a way to do that.

Comment: I agree. Without this feature, it is just too much of a pain in the neck to use the app for casual browsing. This drastically reduces the number of questions I will see, thus reducing the number of questions I can contribute answers to.

We can't answer questions that we don't see and we aren't going to read questions that we have to go to a lot of trouble to read.

The best way to build this feature out would be to make it so my feed can show me all my favorite tags in all my favorite SE sites, all in one list.