# Can a search option be added to home screen or navigation drawer of the Android app?

Tags: feature-request, search, android-app

The following image shows the home page that I see after opening the Android app. Where can I find search option?

[image: Android app home page]

And the following image shows the navigation drawer. I can't find a search option here neither.

[image: Android app navigation drawer]

Am I missing anything?

**Update:** Now I noticed that I get to the search function after selecting a site from the navigation drawer. But why is it not available on the home page? Most of the important and most-used features are hidden deep somewhere in the app. [Another Example here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313808/android-app-no-easy-way-to-filter-by-tags/). It would really help to make them available on the home page or navigation drawer.

Comment: In the iOS app you can only search if you are on a site. So click *Stack Overflow* and see if there is a search bar there.

Comment: yes, mentioned that in the question as update. But being a most used feature it should be accessible easily without requiring to navigate to the site every time. Just a feature request.

Comment: So you want a cross-site search? That is quite expensive and seldom useful in my experience.

Comment: Agree. But was just wondering if there is a way to set sites to search in via settings. It would only make the app more easy to use. Hence this question. I understand the cost factor completely.